# SharpDX DirectWrite rotate text

Tags: c#, rotation, direct2d, sharpdx, directwrite

I wondered how to rotate a text rendered with Direct2D with SharpDX.

Can not find any possiblity in

RenderTarget2D.DrawText()

or

RenderTarget2D.DrawTextLayout()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`Transformation Matrix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756655(v=vs.85).aspx#creating_transformation_matrices) and more precisely - a [rotation transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd372285(v=vs.85).aspx) via a 3x2 matrix.

pseudo example:

```
RenderTarget2D.BeginDraw;
try
  // your regular drawings
  ....

  // save the current tranform
  currentTransform = RenderTarget2D.GetTransform;

  // set a 90 degree rotation around the (100,100);
  RenderTarget2D.SetTransform(Matrix3x2F.Rotation(90, Point2F(100,100))); 

  // do your rotated text drawings
  RenderTarget2D.DrawText();

  // restore your previous/original transform
  RenderTarget2D.SetTransform(currentTransform);
finally
  RenderTarget2D.EndDraw;
end;
```